why it is saying no named parameter?
lib/main.dart:868:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'layers'.
        layers: [
        ^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_map-6.1.0/lib/src/map/widget.dart:29:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const FlutterMap({
        ^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'D:\app\sggsapp\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I need to resolve this error in my dart code. I tried a lot and also explore many alternative approaches but nothing works

The problem is with the plugin version. According to official documentation, the latest version of flutter_map plugin contains changed list of arguments, compared to your code. I need to look at pubspec.yaml file to be sure, but if this is actually the case, you could update your codebase, or downgrade the plugin version.

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Map Screen'),
),
body: FlutterMap(
options: MapOptions(
center: LatLng(23.553, 87.309), // Initial map center
zoom: 14.0, // Initial zoom level
),
layers: [
TileLayer(
urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'], // OSM tile servers
),
],
),
);
}
}     this is the area of the error

Please don't use answers as comments. If you have a question about the question, please post a comment to the question instead.

My reputation score does not allow comments yet.
